# How to stop on duplicate entry (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I have a simple code that asks a user to input items and stores them into an array. I would like to make it so the program stops running when the last entry is the same as the first.

so for example this would stop the program because Cookie it both the first item in the array and the last. But it's also ok to have duplicates with in the array like "Sugar" in this example:

```
Enter the item: Cookie
Enter the item: Sugar
Enter the item: Milk
Enter the item: Sugar
Enter the item: Salt
Enter the item: Cookie
```

**Main.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Decide the number of items
    int numOfItems = 20;

    //Create a string array to store the names of your items
    String arrayOfNames[] = new String[numOfItems];
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfNames.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter Item " + (i+1) + " : ");
        arrayOfNames[i] = scan.nextLine();
    }

    //Now show your items's name one by one
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfNames.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Item # " + (i+1) + " : ");
        System.out.print(arrayOfNames[i] + "\n");
    }

   }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is this a **Cook** or **Dish** or just a **Grocery**?

Comment: @Yahya not sure why it matters, but it's a Grocery list

Comment: It matters if you wanna simulate it in OO program.. another question: Do you consider `Cookie` a duplicate because it came the ***first*** item in the list or because of its ***type***?

Comment: @Yahya Just because it's both the first and the last item not because of it's type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding a simple `if-condition` with `equals()` method. you need do add following `if-condition`.

```
if(Temp.equals(arrayOfNames[0])) // readed Temp equals to first element.
```

Try this code:-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Decide the number of items
    int numOfItems = 20,maxItems=0; // total items may vary

    //Create a string array to store the names of your items
    String arrayOfNames[] = new String[numOfItems];
    String Temp="";                              // for temporary storage
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfNames.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter Item " + (i+1) + " : ");

        Temp= scan.nextLine();
        if(Temp.equals(arrayOfNames[0])){      
            maxItems=i;
            break;
        }
        else{
            arrayOfNames[i]=Temp;
        }
    }

    //Now show your items's name one by one
    for (int i = 0; i < maxItems; i++) {
        System.out.print("Item # " + (i+1) + " : ");
        System.out.print(arrayOfNames[i] + "\n");
    }

   }
}
```

**Output :-**

```
Enter Item 1 : Cookie
Enter Item 2 : Sugar
Enter Item 3 : milk
Enter Item 4 : Sugar
Enter Item 5 : Salt
Enter Item 6 : Cookie
Item # 1 : Cookie
Item # 2 : Sugar
Item # 3 : milk
Item # 4 : Sugar
Item # 5 : Salt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the number of items will be entered by the user then this code will be helpful,

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter name:");
        String temp = sc.next();
        if(al.isEmpty() != true)
        {
            if(temp.equals(al.get(0)))
                break;
        }
            al.add(temp);
    }
     for(int i = 0;i<al.size();i++)
     {
         System.out.println(al.get(i));
     }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

More sophisticated **OO Program** Example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Grocery {

    List<String> basket; // list of items in the basket

    //constructor of Grocery with number of items provided
    public Grocery(int numberOfItems) {
        basket = new ArrayList<>(numberOfItems); // initialize basket
    }


    /**
     * Add item to basket only if it is not similar to the first item
     * return true if succeeded otherwise return false if it's duplicate
     * @param item
     * @return
     */
    public boolean addItem(String item) {
        if(basket.size()==0) return basket.add(item);
        if(!basket.get(0).equals(item)) {
            return basket.add(item);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Remove specific item in the basket
     * or all items by name if "all" is true
     * @param item
     */
    public void removeItem(String item, boolean all) {
        if(all) {
            for(String i : basket) {
                if(i.equals(item)) {
                    basket.remove(i);
                }
            }
        }else {
            basket.remove(item);
        }
    }

    // method to empty the basket
    public void emptyBasket() {
        basket.clear();
    }


    /**
     * Override toString() to provide your own
     * textual representation of the basket
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = "";
        for(int i=0; i<basket.size(); i++) {
            s += "Item #" + (i+1) + " : " + basket.get(i) + "\n";
        }

        return s;
    }

    // TEST
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Decide the number of items
        int numOfItems=0;

        System.out.print("Enter How Many Items: ");

        try {
            numOfItems = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine().trim());
        }catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.print("Number of items you entered is invalid!");
            System.exit(0);
        }


        Grocery grocery = new Grocery(numOfItems);

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfItems; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter Item " + (i+1) + " : ");
            if(!grocery.addItem(scan.nextLine())) {
                System.out.println("First Item Duplicate Detected!");
                //break;
                System.exit(0);
            };
        }

        scan.close();

        System.out.println(grocery.toString());
    }

}
```

## Test

[image: Test]

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a condition that if the current element matches first element, then break out of the for loop.

```
String first=null; 
for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfNames.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter Item " + (i+1) + " : ");
        arrayOfNames[i] = scan.nextLine();
        if (i==0){
            first=arrayOfNames[i];
        }else{
            if(first==arrayOfNames[i]){break;}
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you should be able to do a if statement in here to find out if array[0] = array[i]

```
if (i > 0 && (arrayOfNames[0] == arrayOfNames[i])) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your for loop condition to:

```
for (int i = 0; i == 0 || arrayOfNames[i] != arrayOfNames[0]; i++)
```